# Why is this comment not obsolete?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

<strike>[Link to the comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599344/possible-reasons-for-skipped-numbers-in-names-of-drive-partitions#comment835533_599344)</strike> *Deleted, see accepted answer*

A user made a guess (a correct one), requested some additional information, then the same user wrote a full reponse containing the comment, albeit not word by word. Isn't this obsolete, as it is redundant given the answer posted below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I declined the flag. Somehow I completely missed the answer. No idea how, but I did. On a second look the comment is indeed obsolete and I have removed it.

My mistake, sorry.

Comment: It is thus proven that a toy lizard is also human.

Comment: @muru A toy lizard is not a human, of course.